# Applying limit and offset to an array

Tags: ruby, array, pagination

I'm refactoring an old gateway and came across the following method:

```
def apply_limit_and_offset(options)
  limit  = options[:limit]
  offset = options[:offset]

  @result = if offset
    @result.drop offset
  else
    @result
  end

  @result = if limit
    @result.first limit
  else
    @result
  end

  @result
end
```

`@result` is an `Array` of objects.

Any suggestions on how to refactor this?  It works just fine, but multiple `if` statements make me feel gross.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some notes:

- Be consistent with the use of parens.
- Use ternary expressions (`?`) to reduce short conditionals.
- If you are using Ruby >= 2.0, check [named keywords](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments).
- The resulting expression of an assignment is its value, so you can remove the last `@result`
- What looks gross to me are those in-place updates of `@result`, but this goes beyond the scope of the question.

With Ruby >= 2.0, I'd write:

```
def apply_limit_and_offset(limit: nil, offset: nil)
  @result = offset ? @result.drop(offset) : @result
  @result = limit ? @result.first(limit) : @result
end
```

Comment: named keywords are really nice, i had no idea about them.  thanks!

Comment: That's some pretty code; nice and elegant. +1

Comment: You could also write the first line, `@result.shift(offset) if offset`.

Answer (score 4):

Your operation is basically equivalent to [`Array#slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice), so that is how I would write it.

```
def apply_limit_and_offset(options)
  @result = @result.slice(options[:offset] || 0,
                          options[:limit] || @result.length) || []
end
```

`#slice` appears to tolerate an `options[:limit]` that goes beyond the end of the array.  However, if `options[:offset]` is out of range, then `#slice` returns `nil`, so we need to add `|| []` at the end to make it an empty array.

Comment: Very nice, but where's your usual thorough explanation? Why does this work for various case? For example, what if `offset >= @result.size` or  `0 <= offset < @result.size` and `offset + limit >= @result.size`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Indeed, the original version was all wrong.